# present UIImagePickerController from UIModalPresentationFormSheet in landscape mode (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to present UIImagePickerController from controller presented on iPad in UIModalPresentationFormSheet mode.

But I'm always getting the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

```
- (void)showPickerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How can I present it in landscape mode?